# How to change z-index of the FlxSprite in FlxGroup?

Tags: sprite, z-index, haxe, haxeflixel

I have a heterogeneous FlxGroup contains: 10 **FlxSprite** and 4 **FlxText**. I add all objects with **add(obj)** function and their z-indexes determined by add function.

I want to change z-index values of objects in my FlxGroup dynamically while program is running (ex: With mouse click).

I tried things like:

- **this.setChildIndex(object, i)** but there is no function like this
- **this.add(object)** tried to add object which  is already added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With FlxGroups, the "z-index" is nothing but the array position of the object within the FlxGroup's "members" array. So if you have some FlxGroup "mygroup" it would be simply a matter of changing where your object is in the array "mygroup.members".

EDIT: And to be perfectly clear, it draws in order from the first element to the last, so array position 0 is the "bottom" of the stack.

EDIT 2: Also, just an FYI: FlxState's use the exact same method with their "members" array / add()/remove() logic as well. They're basically glorified FlxGroups themselves.

Comment: Thanks Larsius! You helped me so much not only for this question but also previous questions.

Comment: No problem :) I just follow the Haxe StackOverflow twitter bot and answer questions when I can.... seems like 90% of them are HaxeFlixel questions, the one framework I happen to know anything about XD